What is the idiomatic way to accept arguments to a function that may be mutually exclusive?
I'm building a small library that exposes a function:
await printLib({optionsObj})
Currently, the options parameter is an object with different (optional) properties.
A?: <boolean>
B?: <boolean>
C?: <boolean>

Users can pass either true or false to any option. BUT A and B cannot be both true, or else an error is thrown.
In my case, although A and B cannot be true at the same time, B and C can have the same boolean values.
How to place my arguments so that users have an intuitive sense of which options can go together and which can't?
Does it call for a redesign of the function?
One solution is to take string values as the parameter: "A" | "B" | "C". However, this should be applied when all the possible options (A,B,C) are mutually exclusive - either A or B or C.


How to place my arguments so that users have an intuitive sense of which options can go together and which can't?

The general solution would involve creating a type definition (e.g. a .d.ts file), TypeScript would be helpful in this case.
type Options = {
  A: boolean;
  C?: boolean;
} | {
  B: boolean;
  C?: boolean;
};
declare function printLib(options: Options): Promise<any>;

This also ensures that either A or B is provided. C can be provided in both options, or omitted.
Using booleans for mutually-exclusive might not be a good fit, and as you pointed out an union can be used:
type Options = {
  AorB: "A" | "B";
  C?: boolean;
};
declare function printLib(options: Options): Promise<any>;


I fiddled with your second option. And upon further fiddling, it was clear that having all options be mutually exclusive would be most intuitive for users. So, I rewrote the function to accept string options: "A" | "B" | "C". Thanks for the input.
